# Reading Data from Temp Table in Snowflake into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to query data from Snowflake into a Jupyter Notebook. Since some columns were not present in the original table, I did create a temporary table which had the required new columns. Unfortunately, due to work restrictions, I couldn't show the whole output here. But when I did run the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` command, got the following output.

```
Table CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NEW successfully created.
```

Here is the query I used to make the `TEMP` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NEW AS
SELECT ID,
   VERIFICATION_PROFILE,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'identityMindMostRecentResults')::VARCHAR AS identitymind,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'identityMindMostRecentResults."mm:1"')::VARCHAR AS mm1,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'identityMindMostRecentResults."mm:2"')::VARCHAR AS mm2,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'identityMindMostRecentResults.res')::VARCHAR AS res,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'identityMindMostRecentResults."ss:1"')::VARCHAR AS sanctions,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'autoVerified.facts.account.riskScore')::VARCHAR AS riskscore,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'autoVerified.facts.giact.verificationResponse')::VARCHAR AS GIACT,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'autoVerified.facts.account.type')::VARCHAR AS acct_type,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'autoVerified.verified')::VARCHAR AS verified,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'bankInformationProvided')::VARCHAR AS Bank_info_given,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'businessInformationProvided')::VARCHAR AS Business_info_given,
   get_path(VERIFICATION_PROFILE,'autoVerified.facts.account.industry.riskLevel')::VARCHAR AS industry_risk
FROM DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT
WHERE DATEDIFF('day',TO_DATE(TIME_UPDATED),CURRENT_DATE())<=90
```

I would like to mention that `VERIFICATION_PROFILE` is a JSON blob, hence I had to use `get_path` to retrieve the values. Moreover, keys like `mm:1` are originally in double quotes, so I did use it as it is, and it is working fine in snowflake.

Then using snowflake connector python, I did try to run following query;

```
 import pandas as pd
 import warnings
 import snowflake.connector as sf

 ctx = sf.connect(
 user='*****',
  password='*****',
 account='*******',
 warehouse='********',
 database='DATA_LAKE',
 schema='CUSTOMER'
)
 #create cursor
curs = ctx.cursor()


sqlnew2 = "SELECT * \
FROM DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NEW;"
curs.execute(sqlnew2)
df = curs.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Here `curs` is the cursor object created earlier. Then I got the following message;

```
ProgrammingError: 002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
Object 'DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_NEW' does not exist or not authorized.
```

May I know does snowflake connector allow us to query data from temporary tables pr not? Help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the exact `CREATE TEMP TABLE` command?  What I'm interested in is any quotes or case of the table that might cause the reference on the `SELECT` to be incorrect.  Also, as Felipe mentions below, if the Notebook kernel has been reset or the connection severed in any way, the temp table will no longer exist.

Comment: If possible share the sample python script?

Comment: @ Sriga please see the edits. I did add the script I am using to make connections. And I would like to mention that for  a table it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables only live as long as the session they were created lives:

> Temporary tables can have a Time Travel retention period of 1 day; however, a temporary table is purged once the session (in which the table was created) ends so the actual retention period is for 24 hours or the remainder of the session, whichever is shorter.

You might want to use a transient table instead:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#comparison-of-table-types

Comment: OP is saying they are using the same cursor connection in the Notebook, so the connection should be persisting with the Notebook.

Comment: @MikeWalton as you said to the poster - it would help a lot if they included the full code